# Fastest way to unlock everything in 007 Nightfire?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, nightfire-007

What is the fastest way to unlock everything in 007 Nightfire? Codes are okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cheat codes are accessible under "codenames" from the main menu.

[image: Secret Unlocks Menu]

## All Modes

- All Gadget Upgrades - **Q LAB** (with a space)

## Single Player

- Level Select (unlock all missions in story mode) - **PASSPORT**

## Multiplayer

- All Multiplayer Characters - **PARTY**
- All Multiplayer Modes - **GAMEROOM**
- Explosive Scenery Option (Explosive Barrels in Maps) - **BOOM**

Some guides mistakenly imply that explosive scenery may be unlocked through **Q LAB**, but this is not the case. **BOOM** must be entered to unlock explosive scenery.

Many guides list redundant codes, when fewer codes produce the same effect. For example, **PARTY** unlocks every character, but there are 18 codes to unlock individual characters instead.